# Outbound VPC proxy for two AZ with 2 proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, subnet, vpc

I have a VPC with two back subnets,
each subnet is on a different AZ,
and each AZ has a proxy to go on the internet
is it possible to have a loadbalacer which allows each EC2 created in an AZ to use its proxy
to avoid data traffic between AZ

thank you

Comment: Which proxy? Nat?

Comment: you want to proxy or NAT/NAT gateway?